# Analysis: Prove the converse

Tags: analysis, limits

It can be shown that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = |L|$. Is the converse of this result true?

Comment: What is [an], please?

Comment: $3,\pi,3,\pi,3,\pi,\dots$.

Comment: an is just any sequence. the square brackets should be modulus signs

Comment: @Robert I've edited your question to change the square brackets to the more typical mod bars, is this what you meant?

Comment: yeah thats exactly it, thanks

Comment: Then $3,-3,3,-3,3,-3,\dots$. (I had assumed that square brackets meant the greatest integer function, a once upon a time common convention.)

Answer (score 4):

Just take for example the sequence 1,-1,1,-1,1,-1...